# Meteor load order running counter to documentation and other anamolies. Full example included

Tags: meteor

I still can't quite get Meteor's load order fully under control. I use a lot of 3rd-party scripts when using Bootstrap templates with animations and a lot of these scripts break because they are created with the traditional load order in mind for DOM nodes.

Meteor does not follow this traditional load order, so a lot of times DOM nodes aren't ready when the scripts fire.

I made a simple Meteor app that console logs a message each time a script inside of a particular folder or template.rendered callback is loaded.

https://github.com/fuzzybabybunny/meteor-load-order-test

You can see it deployed here (open up Chrome Console)

http://load-order-test.meteor.com/

There are a few strange things going on.

- main.js and main.html are actually loaded very soon, counter to what the documentation says: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp
- all the DOM nodes are actually created *earlier* than expected
- with six templates that still have yet to have their .rendered() callbacks fired, the max number of DOM nodes has already been reached. We should expect more DOM nodes to be added with each .rendered() callback being fired.

Can someone help explain why I'm seeing these strange things?

Also, is there a surefire way to only run a script once all DOM nodes have been created? Currently it seems like using jQuery to append `<script>` tags somewhere on the DOM inside of `Template.Layout.rendered` would be the most foolproof.

```
Template.Layout.rendered = function(){

    console.log('layout template rendered and the number of DOM nodes is ' + document.getElementsByTagName('*').length);
    $('head').append('<script src="/javascript/domCompleteScript.js"></script>');

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, slightly further down the page:

> **client/lib/**               # code for the client to be loaded first
>
> This folder is for compatibility JavaScript libraries that rely on variables declared with var at the top level being exported as globals. Files in this directory are executed without being wrapped in a new variable scope. These files are executed before other client-side JavaScript files.

I would try putting the 3rd-party scripts into the following places, just to see what works best:

- **client/lib**
- **client/compatibility**
- **lib**